# TSQL - Counting the difference over a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

If I have the following data structure like the one below, where there is a total count of product by category, along with the date that it was counted, how could I calculate the difference among all the values.

For example, the difference of Thing1 at store ABC would be -4. However if my actual data there are many more dates than just these two. So I would need to calculate the difference between every date for a product, and on a more broader range such as quarterly. This is using SQL Server 2014

```
Store | Product  | Total  | Date      |
ABC   | Thing1   | 6      | 1-1-2013  |
ABC   | Thing2   | 2      | 1-1-2013  |
XYZ   | Thing1   | 4      | 1-1-2013  |
XYZ   | Thing2   | 7      | 1-1-2013  |
ABC   | Thing1   | 2      | 5-1-2013  |
ABC   | Thing2   | 4      | 5-1-2013  |
XYZ   | Thing1   | 3      | 5-1-2013  |
XYZ   | Thing2   | 9      | 5-1-2013  |
```

Comment: It is always good to tell the version of sql server you are using. better to use tags

Comment: *...  the difference of Thing1 at store ABC would be -4* ... the difference to what?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Just edited the original post and added SQL Server version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on SQL 2012 or later you can use query below:

```
;with cte as (
    select *
    , LEAD(Total) over (partition by Store, Product order by Store, Product, Dt) NextTotal
    from #t
)
select Store, Product, Dt, (NextTotal - Total) as Delta
from cte
where (NextTotal - Total) is not null
order by Dt, Store, Product
```

**Test it:**

```
create table #t (Store varchar(10), Product varchar(10), Total int, Dt date)

insert into #t values
('ABC', 'Thing1', 6, '1-1-2013'),
('ABC', 'Thing2', 2, '1-1-2013'),
('XYZ', 'Thing1', 4, '1-1-2013'),
('XYZ', 'Thing2', 7, '1-1-2013'),
('ABC', 'Thing1', 2, '5-1-2013'),
('ABC', 'Thing2', 4, '5-1-2013'),
('XYZ', 'Thing1', 3, '5-1-2013'),
('XYZ', 'Thing2', 9, '5-1-2013')
```

**Result:**

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ Store ║ Product ║     Dt     ║ Delta ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║ ABC   ║ Thing1  ║ 2013-01-01 ║    -4 ║
║ ABC   ║ Thing2  ║ 2013-01-01 ║     2 ║
║ XYZ   ║ Thing1  ║ 2013-01-01 ║    -1 ║
║ XYZ   ║ Thing2  ║ 2013-01-01 ║     2 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

<sub>*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*</sub>

Comment: no purpose to repeat the partition by in the order by

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have SQL Server 2012 (and thus the LEAD function) this will work for you.

```
create table #Inventory
(
    Store   varchar(10),
    Product     varchar(10),
    Total       int,
    DateCounted Date
)

insert into #Inventory values ('ABC', 'Thing1', 6, '2013-01-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('ABC', 'Thing2', 2, '2013-01-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('XYZ', 'Thing1', 4, '2013-01-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('XYZ', 'Thing2', 7, '2013-01-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('ABC', 'Thing1', 2, '2013-05-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('ABC', 'Thing2', 4, '2013-05-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('XYZ', 'Thing1', 3, '2013-05-01')
insert into #Inventory values ('XYZ', 'Thing2', 9, '2013-05-01')

;
with #InventoryChange as
(
    select rownum = row_number() over 
    (
        partition by Store, Product
        order by Store, Product, DateCounted
    ), Store, Product, Total, DateCounted
    from #Inventory
)

select a.*, b.Total - a.Total as Difference
from #InventoryChange a
left join #InventoryChange b on a.Store = b.Store and a.Product = b.Product and a.rownum = b.rownum - 1
```

I found this technique [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

If by difference, you mean the difference between the first and last totals based on date, then one method uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select store, product,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then total end) as first_total
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then total end) as last_total,
       (max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then total end) -
        max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then total end)
       ) as diff       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by store, product order by date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by store, product order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1
group by store, product;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TEMP (Store , Product  , Total  , DT)
AS (
SELECT 'ABC'   , 'Thing1'   , 6      , '1-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'ABC'   , 'Thing2'   , 2      , '1-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'XYZ'   , 'Thing1'   , 4      , '1-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'XYZ'   , 'Thing2'   , 7      , '1-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'ABC'   , 'Thing1'   , 2      , '5-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'ABC'   , 'Thing2'   , 4      , '5-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'XYZ'   , 'Thing1'   , 3      , '5-1-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 'XYZ'   , 'Thing2'   , 9      , '5-1-2013' from dual 
)

select Store, Product, max(DT),
min(TOTAL) keep (dense_rank FIRST order by DT desc) - min(TOTAL) keep (dense_rank LAST order by DT desc) as DIFF
from temp
group by Store, Product
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
STORE PRODUCT MAX(DT)        DIFF
----- ------- -------- ----------
ABC   Thing1  5-1-2013         -4 
ABC   Thing2  5-1-2013          2 
XYZ   Thing1  5-1-2013         -1 
XYZ   Thing2  5-1-2013          2
```